# Is there a cleaner solution to this distribution problem?

Tags: combinatorics

> In how many ways can I distribute 20 candy canes to 7 children, if each child must receive at least one, and two of the children are twins who insist on receiving the same amount?

The obvious solution is doing casework on each possibility and finding $\dbinom{17}{4}+\dbinom{15}{4}+\dots +\dbinom{5}{4}$, but is there a solution that doesn't require such calculation? Also, is there some identity that I can use to simplify the calculation if there is no better counting solution? I expanded each of the coefficients, and I can't really find anything to help with the calculation other than canceling out some things, but that still requires some mindless calculation.

Answer (score 1):

The number you are interested in is the number of solutions to

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + 2x_6 = 20$$ where $$x_i >= 1$$

By considering generating functions namely $\frac{1}{1-x}$ and $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$ we are interested in the 13th (20 -7)th coefficient of $$(\frac{1}{1-x})^6\frac{1}{1+x}$$

Which is the sum over $k$ from $0$ to $n$ of $$(-1)^{n-k}\binom{k + 5}{5}$$ for $n = 13$, which is (I suppose there's lots of ways to see this, e.g. induction)

$$\frac{4n^5 + 70n^4 + 460n^3 + 1400n^2 + 1936n + 945 + 15(-1)^n }{960}$$

Putting in $n = 13$ we get $4956$ agreeing with the easier route.